# Created an EXE file with pyinstaller but starts up slow

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've relatively new to programming but I've created my first application and created an exe file using pyinstaller. It runs really well and does exactly what I want it to!!

Problem is it starts up really slow. How do I know what it is doing when it's starting up and how can I try and make it run more efficiently. I'm running a pretty good computer so I don't think its the hardware. I've imported a lot of modules and the file size is 345MB.

Sorry I know my question may not be answerable but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pyinstaller includes to many libraries in your program. So the best solution is to create a virtual environment and install in that environment only the libs you need. Then build your program from that environment.

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Another solution is to reduce the size by excluding some big packages.

https://intellipaat.com/community/15147/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe

Here is a good example how to exclude some libs in the pyinstaller command. When you use libraries like "pandas" which are very big then it's included in the exe file. Here you could try to exclude some folders that are very big and you don't need in your program.